# JQuery append div.class to it's label

Tags: jquery, html, append, each

I want to append each .quiz__control-feedback contents to the .mPos radio button it is associated with. That being the label before each with a class of .mPos. I am only showing the relevant checked radio buttons with the class .mPos. There are actually 5 options for each radio group one being correct.  At the moment when the quiz is submitted .quiz__control-feedback quiz is at the end of each radio button group.

```
<p>
    <input type="radio" name="a01-q02" value="a01-01-q02" data-set="a01-q02" id="a01-q02-e03">
        <label for="a01-q02-e03" class="mPos">Only children with complex additional needs</label>
</p>
<div class="quiz__control-feedback quiz__control-feedback--incorrect">
    <span class="quiz__control-feedback-label">
        Incorrect
    </span>
</div>
<p>
    <input type="radio" name="a01-q04" value="a01-01-q04" data-set="a01-q04" id="a01-q04-e03">
    <label for="a01-q04-e03" class="mPos">If the family has not undertaken relevant training about the NDIS</label>
</p>
<div class="quiz__control-feedback quiz__control-feedback--correct">
    <span class="quiz__control-feedback-label">
        Correct
    </span>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
$("label.mPos").each(function(){
    $(this).append( $('.quiz__control-feedback') );
});
```

But, this appends all instances of .quiz__control-feedback to the second or last checked radio button.

What am I doing wrong? Please let me know if I need to add more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will select the `quiz__control-feedback` that is right after the `label` and append it.

`$(this).parent()` will select the `p` tag and using `.next()` after that will select the `quiz__control-feedback` class

```js
$("label.mPos").each(function() {
  $(this).append($(this).parent().next('.quiz__control-feedback'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="a01-q02" value="a01-01-q02" data-set="a01-q02" id="a01-q02-e03">
  <label for="a01-q02-e03" class="mPos">Only children with complex additional needs</label>
</p>
<div class="quiz__control-feedback quiz__control-feedback--incorrect">
  <span class="quiz__control-feedback-label">
        Incorrect
    </span>
</div>
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="a01-q04" value="a01-01-q04" data-set="a01-q04" id="a01-q04-e03">
  <label for="a01-q04-e03" class="mPos">If the family has not undertaken relevant training about the NDIS</label>
</p>
<div class="quiz__control-feedback quiz__control-feedback--correct">
  <span class="quiz__control-feedback-label">
        Correct
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Carsten unfortunately that did not work. I'll play with it some more. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: @LaurenceL Are you sure your code looks like the one on your page, if you want, make sure you code is 100% equal to the example in your snippe

Comment: HI Carsten I'm going through it again now. Its a developers who left and I have to update. Driving me nuts. I just noticed .quiz__control-feedback is added dynamically which will affect the outcome.

Comment: @LaurenceL If you can try to make your example snippet, as close as possible to your actual code.

Comment: I manually updated the code to test and added it to the snippet you posted. This time it has all the options. I appreciate you taking the time to assist :-)